# SqlConnection.Open() hangs in .NET Core Consol project, but connects fine in a regular C# console project

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

My program connects to the server fine in a C# console project using the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = 
                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();

            string connectionString = "Data Source=IPOfServer;" +
                "Initial Catalog=nameOfDatabase;"+
                "User ID=USERNAME;" +
                "Password=PASSWORD";

            conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Before Connection");
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open");
                conn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Can't Connect; Error:{0}", ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

And outputs:

```
Hello World!
Before Connection
Connection Open
Connection Closed
```

When I try the exact same code in a .NET Core Console project, my output is:

```
Hello World!
Before Connection
```

But the program does not ever error or end. It just hangs forever.

I am using the packages `System.Data.Common` and `System.Data.SqlClient`
It is a MSSQL 2005 Server that I am attempting to connect to.

What am I doing wrong/how do I connect to my server using a .NET Core Console project? I looked into using the `EntityFramework`, but would prefer to not use it unless that is my only option.

Comment: Are these two programs being run on the same machine?

Comment: Default connection timeout [should be 15 seconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx). What happens if you set it manually to something small?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes they are both being run from the same machine

Comment: @GSerg I manually set the timeout to 5 seconds, it still hangs indefinitely

Comment: The next step I would try is get a program like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) and see what is happening on the wire between the two endpoints. Check and see if it even tries to connect. The only possible cause I can think of right now is a firewall rule that lets your first program through but not the second.

Comment: What happens to the yellow mark if you debug/step over conn.Open()? Does it stay/hang there or jump out somewhere?

Comment: @IngoB it still stays/hangs there

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, I'll try that next

Comment: It works in my test case (hmm, well, SQL Server 2014). Are you using the current nuget version of System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Try to connecto to newer version of sql server. You don't do nothing wrong, maybe it's bug in combination with specific version of sql server.

Comment: @IngoB I believe so, I'm using System.Data.SqlClient version 4.3.1. It works for me in a c# console project, but just not in a .NET Core Console project

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Haven't been able to figure it out using Fiddler. I noticed though that upon rebooting my computer, when I try to run the .NET Core Console Application that I am prompted for my Login password and `vmmap` is in the header of the terminal window. But running the C# Console Application runs the program as expected without the prompt to Login beforehand... Not sure if this could be related to anything.

Comment: @TcKs My program runs when I connect to a newer version of sql server, apparently Core is unable to connect to MSSQL 2005. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My program runs when I connect to a newer version of sql server, apparently Core is unable to connect to MSSQL 2005. Thank you [@TcKs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20382/tcks%20%22@TcKs) for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

> Open existing Solution in Visual Studio 2015. Now, add new Client
>   Library .NET Core project in Solution.
>
> Open Add New Project Screen through Solution Context Menu >> Add >>
>   New Project Or File >> New >> Project. Select Class Library (.NET
>   Core) Template through Installed >> Templates >> Visual C# >> .NET
>   Core. Name project as “WebApplicationCore.NetCore.DataAccess”. Set
>   suitable location as “C:\ASP.NET Core\Welcome To .NET Core 1.0\
>   ASP.NET Core” (selected by default to solution root). Click OK button.
>
> It will create a new class library project.
>
> Add Reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, using one of
>   following methods.
>
> Open Package Manger Console through Tools >> NuGet Packet Manger >>
>   Package Manger Console and run install command "Install-Package
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" for
>   WebApplicationCore.NetCore.DataAccess project.
>
> Open NuGet Manager through WebApplicationCore.NetCore.DataAccess
>   Reference context menu >> References >> Manage NuGet Packages. in
>   Browse tab search for "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" and
>   install.
>
> Rename Class1 as BaseDataAccess and add the required implementation to
>   connect to SQL Server Database.

[- Source (csharpcorner)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-core-1-0-connecting-sql-server-database/)

Similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38510740/7616709)

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow app bugged around ^^

Comment: "So it seems like you cannot connect to a sql server like the usual way." That is the exact opposite of what the accepted answer of the link to the stack overflow question says.

Comment: There is no accepted answer but ok :) the solution seems like a workaround, because i dont need to add my namespace in my project.json lol

Comment: I dont understand why you downvote my answer if you or the op havent even tried to follow the tutorial on csharpcorner. I would love to add these links as a comment but there is no chance with <50 rep

Comment: Its the same thing as adding `System.Data.dll` to a normal .NET project. the only diffrence is your csproj does not include it by default for .NET core, but that would cause a compiler error not a runtime hang. Also, the downvote was for posting  a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: This actually helped me fix my problem.