# .NET Core 2.0 Strongly Typed DataRows

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset, .net-core-2.0

Is there a way to strongly type a DataRow in C# .NET Core 2.0 without using EF nor any ORM? I used datasets on vb.net, but it looks like it's not yet available. Also, it looks like SqlCommandBuilder isn't available either.

I used something like this in vb.net:

```
Public Sub EntityToDataSet(ByRef entity As User, ByRef dataset As MyDataSet)
Dim dr As MyDataSet.UsersRow
dr = dataset.Users.NewUsersRow()
dr.Address = entity.Address
dr.Name = entity.Name
_dataAdapterUsers.Update(dataSet)
End Sub
```

As you can see, the dataset provides strongly typed rows. I want to be able to do something like this on .NET Core.

Comment: Why can't you use EF or another ORM?

Comment: It's a university assignment

Comment: Typed datasets?

Comment: Databases *are* by their very nature, strongly typed (all columns have types). If you have to do your own object mapping... that's not a problem we can just "fix".

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself correctly (english is not my main language). I need to strongly type the datarows as I used to do with the dataset. I added an example.

Comment: Too bad the university is choosing VB.NET, I am just noticing you say in your question and you tag your question C#, do you understand that your language is VB.NET and not C#?

Comment: I used VB.NET in the past, now I must do the new work on C# and I was hopping to use .NET Core.

Comment: All the classes are there, what you are probably asking about is the tooling. I did a quick check, VS 15.3 will add a MyDataset.xsd to the project and has a designer tool. I can drag a table from the SoX window but then it stops, apparently I don't have a MSDataSetGenerator installed.

Comment: But yes, too bad your university is 10 years in the past on this.

Comment: @BrianOgden — "Too bad the university is choosing VB.NET." Why is that? VB.NET is a very productive programming language for solving business problems.

Comment: @InteXX C# opens a larger pool of job opportunity, especially important for incoming developers with unproven track records, note: after understanding the OP's question better, the university requirement is C#, the OP just has some old VB.NET code that is trying to associate with his/her assignment implementation

Comment: @Matias does the university require strongly typed DataRows as part of the assignment/project?

Comment: @BrianOgden — "C# opens a larger pool of job opportunity." Point well taken.

Comment: @InteXX ya I inherently have no problem with VB.NET, I would say that in a very small amount of situations C# is more readable, particularly LINQ queries, the choice between C# and VB.NET is more akin to fashion sense than performance or any other real world pro or con. That means it is highly subjective. C# is a more terse language and wins more often simply because of familiar curly braces and semi colon end lines. I definitely prefer C# and think it has a better appearance on "paper" but it is a highly opinionated, dogmatic subject, either language will get one where they need to be.

Comment: @BrianOgden — "... it is a highly opinionated, dogmatic subject" The programming gods wouldn't mind if you said that again. (p.s. Nice answer, by the way.)

Comment: @InteXX haha, thanks, definitely have used both C# and VB.Net extensively, so just trying to be honest :)

Comment: @BrianOgden — Good man :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if [strongly typed DataSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/generating-strongly-typed-datasets), DataRows etc. were available using a .NET Core Stack and ADO.NET [which they are not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510740/is-ado-net-in-net-core-possible), I think you will find in the .NET Core community today that there would be very little use of DataRow or DataSet at all and certainly not as a means to enforce strong typing, [for example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/). That concept of "strongly typed" that ADO.NET provided out of the box for some of its key objects like DataTable, DataRow, Dataset is an old school mentality. If you want a strongly typed solution in this day and age, you simply define your types and throw exceptions when incorrect type casting is attempted, or do not even throw exceptions, C# will throw invalid cast exceptions for you.

I think it also makes sense to say that using a strongly typed DataRow/DataSet implementation is reminiscent of an implementation you might do with ASP.NET Web Forms stack circa 1999-2005. If I remember correctly ADO.NET DataTable and DataSet had these out of the box strongly typed features developers would utilize. But today, the best practices are always to keep things very simple and clean, no out of the box magic that Microsoft used to provide, that magic almost always led to monolithic, hard to maintain software architecture.

I believe the code below is a "strongly typed" solution, using .NET Core 2.0, ADO.NET and not using EF or any other ORM, if you just do not focus on a strongly typed "DataRow" requirement which confuses me a bit that is a requirement from the University, I am guessing that using a DataRow is something you hope to achieve because it is familiar to you from past code you have written.

And keep in mind that MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle database can be designed "strongly typed", and really cannot be easily designed any other way because columns have types like: `varchar`, `int`, `decimal`, `money`, `byte`, `guid`, `nvarchar` etc.

You could make every column in every database a blob or byte and then argue the database is dynamically typed but it is a bit of silly scenario.

C# is a "strongly typed" language.

So with all that said, and as long as the University does not specifically ask that you use DataRow or DataSet to enforce strong typing, then this solution might fit the bill as it still uses ADO.NET:

```
public class AddressModel {
    public string Address1 { get; set; } //this is a strongly typed property
    public int Zip { get; set; } //this is a strongly typed property
}

public List<AddressModel> GetAddress(int addressId) {
    List<AddressModel> addressList = new List<AddressModel>();
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Address1, Zip FROM [dbo].[Address]";
    using (SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (data.Read())
        {
            AddressModel temp = new AddressModel();
            temp.Address1 = Sql.Read<String>(data, "Address1");
            temp.Zip = Sql.Read<Int32>(data, "Zip");
            addressList.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    return addressList;
}

public static class Sql
{
    public static T Read<T>(DbDataReader DataReader, string FieldName)
    {
        int FieldIndex;
        try { FieldIndex = DataReader.GetOrdinal(FieldName); }
        catch { return default(T); }

        if (DataReader.IsDBNull(FieldIndex))
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        else
        {
            object readData = DataReader.GetValue(FieldIndex);
            if (readData is T)
            {
                return (T)readData;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(readData, typeof(T));
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException)
                {
                    return default(T);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31982681/1258525) for the nice `Read` extension method that will throw Invalid Type Cast Exceptions

Comment: @HenkHolterman holding on to a strongly typed DataRow solution means what? What is the purpose of using a strongly typed DataRow, isn't that a pretty deprecated way to implement anyways?

Comment: Yes, it is deprecated but the OP addresses all that. This is a workaround but that's not what was asked for.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: @HenkHolterman you did say that my answer completely misses the point of the question, so you are suggesting that they only relevant answer would be to guide the OP to somehow find a solution using deprecated, perhaps even draconian ADO.NET design patterns/concepts?

Comment: @HenkHolterman you mark down my answer, an answer that tries to help guide the OP to think about and see a solution in a 2017 way and not a circa 1999 way, you are by no means correct in your judgement

Comment: The dv is for "which they are not". As for the rest of your rant, DataReader isn't directly the forefront of tech either, is it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am not ranting at all, I am trying to provide a good explanation and good guidance

Comment: @HenkHolterman and I still attempt to use ADO.NET as I assume that is the requirement of the University, in conjunction with the hope that the University does not require implementation level details such as using some ADO.NET object of strong type enforcement

Comment: According to what you clearly said, I won't be able to obtain what I expected on .NET Core, so I asume this is the best answer I can get. The code you informed looks useful, an I probably wil use it. Thank you.

Comment: @Matias glad it is helpful, it will be a good direction and should be accepted by the University based on the requirements you mentioned

Comment: Strange that your example code returns a List of `AddressModel` but it never actually adds the newly created instance to the list.  At the end of the while loop, it is missing `addressList.Add(temp);`

Answer (score 1):

Strongly-typed datasets are just c# classes generated by the visual studio designer, using ADO.net datasets.  So if ADO.net is supported (which it is, see link below), you should be able to use your existing strongly typed datasets.  Note that I haven't tried it, but it's a topic I should research for an existing code base I have.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/