# Can I use SQL Queries instead of Entity framework in .NET Core clean architecture?

Tags: sql, .net-core, clean-architecture

While researching about the clean architecture of .NET Core, I understand that only Entity Framework is being used.

I wanted to know whether we can use raw SQL queries by making a connection to SQL with connection strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is ADO.NET in .NET Core possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510740/is-ado-net-in-net-core-possible)

Comment: You can use datareader, dataset and dataadapter as in system.data assembly or extension assembly based on .Net Core version

Answer (score 2):

Clean architecture doesn't restricts you to entity frame work. You can also look into micro ORM e.g. Dapper which can be used to write sql queries. It's very powerful and gives you many out of box capabilities e.g. mapping. Infact if you don't want full ORM functionality Dapper is recommended in Microsoft docs.

[Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper)

[Dapper for read queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/cqrs-microservice-reads#use-dapper-as-a-micro-orm-to-perform-queries)